# Vaadin application not working in heroku, getting npm install has not run or failed

Tags: java, npm, heroku, vaadin

When i deploy my vaadin application i get build success, but i get this error in the log: "Couldn't start dev server because '/app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js' doesn't exist. `npm install` has not run or failed." and app isnt working. I have already added the jetty runner plugin and the procfile should be allright too. Anyone knows what is happening? The github link to the project is https://github.com/yaguetskr/launchpool

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the application for production, i.e. run `mvn` with the `-Pproduction` parameter. For Heroku this can be done using the CLI as

```
heroku config:set MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS="-Pproduction"
```